# right method for calculating char spacing in SCSS

Tags: html, css, vue.js, sass

I have an input field which has a design CSS to use it as digit entry
the problem is variation of char or digit width and they misplace on rendering, I'm using VUE and Laravel
please help me to correct that.

here is SCSS :

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
//$char-w: 2ch;
//$gap: .5*$char-w;
//$n-char: 4;
//$in-w: $n-char*($char-w + $gap);
$char-w: 1.5ch;
$gap: $char-w;
$n-char: 4;
$in-w: $n-char*($char-w + $gap);
$letter-spacing: ($in-w - ($n-char*$char-w))/$n-char;
input.digit {
 display: block;
 //margin: 2em auto;
 margin: 5px;
 border: none;
 padding: 0;
 direction: ltr;
 width: $in-w;
 background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg,
     dimgrey 0, dimgrey $char-w,
     transparent 0, transparent $char-w + $gap) 0 100%/ #{$in-w - $gap} 2px no-repeat;
 //font:  "IRANSans Medium", monospace;
 //letter-spacing: $gap;
 letter-spacing: $letter-spacing;

 &:focus {
     outline: none;
     //color: dodgerblue;
 }
}
</style>
```

and HTML section :

```
   </div>
          <input class="digit"
                               type="text"

                               maxlength='4'
                               :disabled="isDisabled.code" value="1111">
                        <input class="digit"
                               type="text"

                               maxlength='4'
                               :disabled="isDisabled.code" value="5555">
                        <input class="digit"
                               type="text"

                               maxlength='4'
                               :disabled="isDisabled.code" value="1234">

    </div>
```

the result is like :
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iu9iB.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [monospace](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace) font, it should render chars of equal width.